# ObjectiveC - Flat file to CoreData

Tags: objective-c, core-data, flat-file

I have a large file with 1 million rows. The file is setup as follows:

A1   B1     C1  D1  E1
A2   B2     C2  D2  E2
A3   B3     C3  D3  E3

I want to read this data into a SQLite database which is managed by CoreData.

What is the most efficient and effective way of doing this?

This could be achieved by either using CoreData & Objective-C or creating an SQLite database that is then imported into the project which uses CoreData.

Answer (score 2):

If this isn't something you need to do on the fly, then I'd probably write a script of some kind that: (1) creates the database/schema, then (2) reads from the file and inserts into the appropriate tables. I'd then import the database into the project.

Comment: I created a travel guide for iPhone that did something like this. We created a tool that read a CSV file and created and inserted corresponding objects into CoreData. You can save the resulting .sqlite file in your project. (Add the file to your "copy resources" build phase.)

Answer (score 1):

here's an example of a method i use in my iOS app to load a delimited text file (using a pipe "|" as the field delimiter) that contains data about several plant and animal species. the file is stored in the app's Documents directory so the user can add/change it via document sharing through iTunes. the file is named 'X.specieslist', where X is the same name as the sqlite database being managed by Core Data. The code checks that a given species isn't already present in the database (based on the 'code' key), and only imports those species not present.

```
- (void)loadSpecies {

    //get path to species file stored in Documents directory
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *basePath = ([paths count] > 0) ? [paths objectAtIndex:0] : nil;
    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *psc = [managedObjectContext persistentStoreCoordinator];
    NSArray *psa = [psc persistentStores];
    NSURL *psurl = [[psa objectAtIndex: 0] URL];
    NSString *filestr = [[psurl lastPathComponent] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @"sqlite" withString: @"specieslist"] ;
    NSString *filePath = [basePath stringByAppendingPathComponent: filestr];

    //create array with each element containing a single line from the input file
    NSArray *speciesRecords = [[NSString stringWithContentsOfFile: filePath encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding error: nil] componentsSeparatedByString: @"\n"];

    if (speciesRecords) {
        int speciesAdded = 0;
        int speciesSkipped = 0;
        NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName: @"Species" inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext];
        NSManagedObject *newSpecies;
        NSDictionary *speciesDictionary;
        NSArray *fieldKeys = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: @"code", @"scientificName", @"commonName", @"family", @"lifeform", @"growthForm", @"lifecycle", @"nativity", @"notes", nil];
        NSArray *fieldValues;
        NSArray *existingRecords = [fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects];
        NSPredicate *speciesCodePred;
        NSArray *speciesMatch;

        for (NSString *species in speciesRecords) {
            fieldValues = [species componentsSeparatedByString: @"|"];

            //check if species code already exists
            speciesCodePred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"code MATCHES %@", [fieldValues objectAtIndex: 0] ];
            speciesMatch = [existingRecords filteredArrayUsingPredicate: speciesCodePred];

            //only add species not already present
            if ([speciesMatch count] == 0) {
                newSpecies = [[NSManagedObject alloc] initWithEntity: entity insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext];
                speciesDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects: fieldValues forKeys: fieldKeys];
                [newSpecies setValuesForKeysWithDictionary: speciesDictionary];
                [newSpecies release];
                speciesAdded++;
            }
            else
                speciesSkipped++;
        }
        [fieldKeys release];
        NSString *speciesSkippedString = (speciesSkipped > 0) ? [NSString stringWithFormat: @" and %d species were skipped because they were already present.", speciesSkipped] : @".";

        UIAlertView *av = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: @"Species List Import" message: [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%d species were added to the database%@", speciesAdded, speciesSkippedString] delegate: nil cancelButtonTitle: @"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [av show];
        [av release];
    }

    else {
        UIAlertView *av = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: @"Species List Import" message: @"A species list file was not present, no species were imported." delegate: nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [av show];
        [av release];
    }
}
```